# Python newbie and unsupported operand

Tags: python

I'm just learning python and am trying to make a program that calculates loan rates.  I keep getting an unsupported operand type for *: 'function' and 'int.'  with references to lines 14 and 8.  I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.  Here is the code:

```
from sys import argv

def payment(amt, rate, yrs) :
    def p(yrs) :
        return 12 * yrs
    def r(rate) :
        return rate / 100 / 12
    return (r * amt) / (1 - ((1 + r) ** (-p)))

if __name__ == "__main__" :
    amt = int(argv[1])
    rate = float(argv[2])
    yrs = int(argv[3])
    print("$%.2f" % payment(amt, rate, yrs))
```

Comment: `r` is a function, and you can't multiply functions and integers. I think you want to call it: `r(rate)`

Comment: Note that you need to call `p` as well

Comment: Which is a good place to note that calling a function/variable `r` or `p` is a bad practice!

Comment: Also, why do you have nested functions?  I do not think you need that complex of a function for your purposes.

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned in the comments, your immediate problem is that (as your exception says) you tried to multiply an integer with a function, and that doesn't make sense. A naïve fix for that would be to call the functions you've defined, as per Mehmet's answer:

```
return (r(rate) * amt) / (1 - ((1 + r(rate)) ** (-p(yrs))))
```

However, you don't really need those functions at all. A simpler version of your `payment()` function might look like this:

```
def payment(amt, rate, yrs) :
    p = 12 * yrs
    r = rate / 100 / 12
    return (r * amt) / (1 - ((1 + r) ** (-p)))
```

Notice that instead of defining functions inside `payment()`, here we're simply assigning the result of the calculation to a variable in each case.

Answer (score 4):

```
from sys import argv

def payment(amt, rate, yrs) :
    def p(yrs) :
        return 12 * yrs
    def r(rate) :
        return rate / 100 / 12
    return (r(rate) * amt) / (1 - ((1 + r(rate)) ** (-p(yrs))))

if __name__ == "__main__" :
    amt = int(argv[1])
    rate = float(argv[2])
    yrs = int(argv[3])
    print("$%.2f" % payment(amt, rate, yrs))
```

at line 8 you should pass arguments to functions:

```
r(rate)
p(yrs)
```

Comment: Yep, you did. Without explaining *anything*.

Comment: @vaultah I see you guys explained in the comments I don't have privilege for making comments to questions. And also you guys didn't post the answer so I post. I can not say more than your explanation. It is injustice. If you know the answer, answer the question why you are commenting. Topic should be answered, this is the aim of this website. Am I right?

Comment: @Mehmet I downvoted because, while the answer does fix OP's code, it doesn't solve their problem, which is that as a beginner in python they've misunderstood how to use functions. I'll happily switch my downvote to an upvote if you explain why OP's original code doesn't work.

Comment: As an aside: there is no justice on Stack Overflow. There are only good posts and bad posts.

Comment: @ZeroPiraeus I don't get it. Why you are answering question in comments instead of answers? Is that the safer way for avoiding from downvotes? I'm actually a newbie user. You guys are experienced in Stack Overflow, so please let the easy questions to novices. How can we get reputation if you do this. Also you are giving downvotes to me. It's not fair. You can simply warn me using comments instead of downvoting. It is an offending thing.

Comment: I usually answer such questions in comments because I don't want to give real answers to bad questions (that's a little boring) and because reputation doesn't mean a lot to me. And please, don't take downvotes personally.

Comment: I'm sorry you guys. As I said I'm a newbie user and I am not accustomed things like that. But I edited my answer as you said. I hope you forgive me.

Comment: @Mehmet no offence was intended. I've removed my downvote, since you've now added some basic explanation to your answer; an even better answer would explain why using nested functions is not a good solution in this case (and indeed, is rarely a good solution unless you're doing things well beyond OP's current level of understanding).

Comment: @ZeroPiraeus thank you :) I get the point. I mean, I understand the situation.

Comment: Mehmet, please try to not take down-votes personally. They are votes on your _answer_, not on you as a person. If you want to get a better idea of how Stack Overflow works (and Stack Exchange communities in general), I urge you to read all the help pages that are linked in the [Help Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). You will be rewarded for your effort! :)

Comment: @Mehmet by the way, your answer got more critical attention than it otherwise might because it was mentioned in the [Python chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6/python). Now that you have the > 20 rep required to participate, you're welcome to join us there :-)

Answer (score 0):

When you *reference* a function, you name it without parentheses. However, in your case, you are trying to *use* the function, so you have to call it with parentheses (and in your case, a variable).

Here is your edited code:

```
from sys import argv

def payment(amt, rate, yrs) :
    def p(yrs) :
        return 12 * yrs
    def r(rate) :
        return rate / 100 / 12
    return (r(rate) * amt) / (1 - ((1 + r(rate)) ** (-(p(yrs)))))

if __name__ == "__main__" :
    amt = int(argv[1])
    rate = float(argv[2])
    yrs = int(argv[3])
    print("$%.2f" % payment(amt, r(rate), p(yrs)))
```

Comment: @PM2Ring got to love the 5 `<sup>` tags